# How to implement pause and resume downloading functionality in iPhone?

Tags: web-services, ipad, resume-download

I have an iPad application in which i have to download file(zip file) from web server.
Now i have to implement functionality like pause and resume downloading.
Is there any sample code or link to get above functionality in my app,
I needed it fast,so please give your suggestion on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a native app or a web app?

Comment: its simple native app having functionality of downloading file from my server

Comment: I don't think you will find a sample code (in objc) to achieve this kind of thing. But good luck.